# What is my lcd density?

Tags: screen

How can I figure out what is my tablet's lcd screen density.

It is a cheapy one with no official site...

Is there any settings option I could check to see the display resolution configurations?
Is there any other way for it?

Answer (score 6):

You probably have a diagonal screen size, and a resolution.  Use the Pythagorean Theorem on the resolution and divide the result by the screen size to get the DPI.

For example, my Vibrant is 4", 800x480.  sqrt(800<sup>2</sup> + 480<sup>2</sup>) / 4 = ~233 dpi.

Answer (score 1):

Even a cheap tablet with no official specs normally mentions the screen resolution on the box, didn't yours?

If not, then you could visit a web page like http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/ (there are many other similar websites out there) or install an app like [Android System Info](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.electricsheep.asi) that will tell you your resolution as well as your DPI.

The DPI is just a measurement of how many pixels there are on an inch of your screen, so if you know your screen resolution, you can measure the size of your screen and calculate the DPI from  there to get the actual density.

Answer (score 0):

I've created small app to check phone screen density. You could check it. [Phone Density Information](http://market.android.com/details?id=m.mokrzycki.phoneifnormations)

Answer (score 0):

If you are rooted, the best way to check is to go to /system and open build.prop, and then check if there is a line called `ro.sf.lcd_density`. This will give you the current LCD density, and you can even change it if you want.